# Data Conversion error on excel import to sql

Tags: sql, ssms

I have the below columns in excel:

[image]

That I am trying to import into a new table in sql through SSMS.

However I keep getting an error message as below:

> (Error)
>   Messages
>   Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "TYPE_CODE" (15) to column "TYPE_CODE" (51).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

My columns in the sql table have been set up as:

```
CREATE TABLE FC04
(
TYPE_CODE int,
SKU varchar(255),
QtyOnHand varchar(255)
);
```

Can anyone advise on a solution or where I am going wrong?

I have made the changes suggested and now the file inputs but I get the output as below when using only 4 lines?

[image]

Comment: type_code in the table is defined as `int` and you are inserting a `varchar`

Comment: when I changed this in then inputs fine but gives me NULL values as SKU and QtyOnHand?  I know there are values???

Comment: First I advise you to try with a version of excel with only a couple of lines. Keep in mind that ALL the values in ALL the rows should be able to be casted. Keep an eye in nulls...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column TYPE_CODE is trying to be imported as int. 
Their values (like **FC04**) cannot be converted to int.

You should change the type in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE FC04
(
TYPE_CODE varchar(255),
SKU varchar(255),
QtyOnHand varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: As a side note ,you might be interested to change QtyOnHand as int

Comment: ...and possibly also SKU as that looks int-y from the sample above!

Comment: Yes, you are right. @User29757114 in general I advise you to review your column types...